# Dual display not working after 16.04 upgrade

Tags: display, monitor, 16.04

I recently upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04 via dist-upgrade. Immediately afterwards, my second monitor stopped working. I am using an AMD 7850 APU, and both monitors are plugged in to the motherboard - One is connected with an HDMI, and one is connected with a DVI. The monitor with the DVI cord is not displaying.

When I open "Displays" in the system settings, both monitors are shown as being detected. I tried disabling and re-enabling the blank monitor with no luck.

Comment: 16.04 had a major change from the perspective of [supporting AMD GPUs](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04). I would suggest you to better go back to 14.04 (since it is a LTS and 15.10 wont be supported after 3 months)if you were using AMD ATI catalyst drivers in 15.10.