# Second monitor not working after Xubuntu 16.04 upgrade

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 16.04, display, monitor

I just upgraded from Xubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 via dist-upgrade.
After I restarted, the monitor that is connected (via HDMI-to-DVI-cable) to my laptop wasn't recognized anymore. I already restarted two times in the hope that the problem just vanishes :) Before the upgrade the setup with the second monitor worked like a charm for 2 years.

If I call xrandr it only shows the laptop-monitor.

```
:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)     345mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     59.93*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

The GUI for managing the monitors only shows the laptop-monitor,too.

Yes, the monitor is turned on. I also turned it off and on again several times in the hope that my laptop would finally recognize it.
Yes the cable is connected. I also unplugged it and plugged it back in, just to be sure.

My laptop contains a Nvidia GeForce GT 650M (`lspci -v`).
The driver for that card seems to be nouveau (`lshw -c video`).

So I don't think I'm affected by those AMD-driver-problems, right?
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04
[Dual display not working after 16.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760940/dual-display-not-working-after-16-04-upgrade)

I also found this thread that seems to be similar to my problem:
[Xubuntu 14.04 does not detect second monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490112/xubuntu-14-04-does-not-detect-second-monitor)
But when I look into my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` I can't find anything like `nomodeset`.

When I connect the monitor and the laptop with a VGA-cable it works. Of course with a hideous resolution :(

So how can I get my laptop to recognize the second monitor via HDMI again?

update:
yesterday I switched from nouveau to the proprietary NVIDIA binary driver (v. 361.42). But it didn't help. If I connect a display via the HDMI port it's just not recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This morning I decided to try it again.
And. It. Just. Worked.
I have no freaking idea why it works now. I tried it several times over the past weeks and today suddenly it worked.

Perhaps there was an update that fixed my problem?

Whatever, I'm happy I have my big monitor back :)